# erro no Fragments setArguments e getArguments

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou tentando passar algumas informações da ActivityMain para um fragement porém o android está reclamando, na ActivityMain eu passo os valores assim:

```
if (f_caixaTexto== null) {
        f_caixaTexto = new PageCaixaTextoFragment();
        f_caixaTexto.setArguments(Constant.getDuvidas(this));

}
adapter.addFragment(f_restituicao, "Duvidas");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

já no meu Fragemento eu recebo os dados assim:

```
public PageCaixaTextoFragment() {
      Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
      CaixaTexto caixaTexto = (CaixaTexto) bundle.getSerializable("bundle");
      titulo_texto = caixaTexto.getTitulo();
      corpo_texto = caixaTexto.getCorpo();
      imagem_int = caixaTexto.getImagem();
}
```

o método **getDuvidas(this)**  tem o seguinte código

```
public static Bundle getDuvidas(Context ctx){
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       String titulo = ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.duvidas_titulo);
       String corpo = ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.duvidas);
       int imagem = R.drawable.ic_group_banco;
       CaixaTexto tmp = new CaixaTexto(titulo,imagem,corpo);
       bundle.putSerializable("bundle",tmp);
       return bundle;
}
```

Mas quando tento executar recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

onde estou errando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `getArguments` deverá ser chamada após o fragment estar criado, tipicamente no metodo `onCreate` fazendo por exemplo:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
}
```